# Cache a dataset in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I was wondering whether I can directly cache a dataset in Google Dataflow platform (like caching RDDs in Spark).

If there is no such feature, how does Dataflow pick hot datasets in the applications, especially if you have multiple hot datasets, and you want to prioritize caching based on the importance of the datasets?

Answer (score 3):

Dataflow has a very different execution model than Spark. In Spark, the central concept is an RDD and the typical mode of working with an RDD is to interactively query it in unpredictable ways; hence, RDDs need caching, potentially controllable by the user.

In Dataflow (Apache Beam), the central concept is a `Pipeline`, built and optimized and executed as a monolithic whole, where `PCollection` (the closest analogue to RDD) is merely a logical node in the pipeline.

Both of these approaches have their advantages, but with Dataflow's approach, Dataflow knows exactly how a `PCollection` will be used in the pipeline, so there is no unpredictability involved and there is no need for a caching strategy.

Dataflow currently materializes some intermediate `PCollection`s in temporary files on Google Cloud Storage, trying to avoid materialization whenever possible by using [fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization). If a `PCollection` is materialized, then a pipeline stage that processes this collection will need to read it from Cloud Storage; otherwise (if the stage is fused with the stage producing the dataset), it will be processing elements of the dataset in-memory, immediately as they are produced, co-located on the worker that produces them.

`GroupByKey` operations and alike (e.g. `Combine`) are special: Dataflow has several implementations of `GroupByKey`, different between batch and streaming pipelines; they either use local disk on VMs to store the data, or use [high-performance Google internal infrastructure](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/introducing-cloud-dataflow-shuffle-for-up-to-5x-performance-improvement-in-data-analytic-pipelines).

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your response. This is a huge assertion "there is no unpredictability involved ..."; this makes the platform suitable for real-time systems. Would you please let me know whether I can find more info about predictability in any of the research publications (e.g., Flume or Millwheel). The main problem is we don't have any control over the tuning part, except choosing the instance type with larger memories. How can I create a cost model based on the input datasets? only experimental? How can I convince my customers that my Dataflow model is optimized and cost-effective? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I mean only that the access pattern for collections is predictable, just like an SQL database knows the whole query plan before executing the query. There's still plenty of other unpredictability: data size and distribution, user code processing durations, etc. "Why beam does not expose almost any tuning knobs" is a good question but outside the scope of a comment, feel free to ask a separate SO question :)